# Is there an app for iPhone to make pictures after a delay?

Tags: iphone, applications

Lets say I want to place the camera without photographer, and take some time to move into the picture.

Is there an app for iPhone to make pictures after a delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Self Timer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/self-timer/id346475986?mt=8)

> Self Timer allows you to delay the shutter release, giving you time
>   between pushing the button and taking the actual photo. Once you push
>   the button, a beeping sound is emitted which becomes faster as the
>   moment of the shot approaches.

[image]